# Difference between mail and sendmail in regards of Laravel 5

Tags: email, sendmail

I wish to have a brainstorm with you all about Laravel 5 and it's mail function. The point is: I have multiple servers with CentOS 7 installed and using them as webservers for laravel 5 based sites. A few days before, I had to move a website from staging to production server. However, the mail function was not working at all.

On the staging site I had the mail driver set to sendmail and worked like a charm. On the other hand, the production server couldn't send a single mail via the website until I've set the mail driver to "mail" insted of "sendmail". Do you guys have any idea why is this happening? All the servers are using sendmail without a second thought but this particular server (doesn't differ from the others) aggrees only with "mail" as mail driver. Why could it be?

Comment: What is  reported in sendmail's log file?

Comment: Nothing, postfix doesn't log anything. Laravel logs the following:
`[2016-05-23 13:28:37] production.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""' in /var/www/my_website/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383`

This was with sendmail. With mail, it worked.